# Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames iptable when running Node.js behind NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, ssl-certificate

I am running both node and nginx in a dockerized environment (with nginx forwarding traffic on port 2443 to 3000 on node, and iptables forwarding 443 > 2443). I have no problems connecting to the server however when my backend tries to upload a file to S3 I get:

```
Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: [s3bucket].s3.amazonaws.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:[mydomain].com, DNS:www.[mydomain].com"
```

(There are no periods in the s3 bucket name - having been reported as an issue in other posts).

My app.js includes:

```
// Trust local proxies
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');
```

My nginx conf:

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
 listen       2443;
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
 access_log   logs/all.access.log  main;
 client_max_body_size 50M;

 # pass requests for dynamic content
 location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
     proxy_pass http://webserver:3000/;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

So how can I avoid this certificate mismatch? Is there a problem in my nginx config. Do I need to do something else in my app.js? Is there something about using iptables that screws with the host?